# Saving file in isolated storage

Tags: c#, save, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I'm working on a gradebook program assignment for a class; the details aren't so important, except to know that I need to be able to save a file and recall it later. I know how to serialize, deserialize, etc, and everything's good there. But the problem comes when I try to save. I'm a bit new to the whole saving data scene, and I don't exactly know the techniques, but what I have seems like it should work - except that every time I try it, I get an error.

```
private static void Save (IList<GradebookEntry> gradebook) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Saving changes. Please wait...");
        using (IsolatedStorageFile stored = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore (IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null)) {
            try {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream ("Temp.utc", FileMode.Create, stored)) {
                    BinaryFormatter bform = new BinaryFormatter ();
                    bform.Serialize (isoStream, gradebook);
                    string[] s = stored.GetDirectoryNames ();
                    stored.DeleteFile ("Gradebook.utc");
                    stored.MoveFile ("Temp.utc", "Gradebook.utc"); // #!!
                }
                Console.WriteLine ("Changes saved.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Saving failed. Reason: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally {
                if (stored.FileExists("Temp.utc")) {
                    stored.DeleteFile ("Temp.utc");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The marked line, where I try to move the file, is where I have problems. Everything else works fine, but when I reach that line, it throws an IsolatedStorageException with the message "Operation not permitted". I've looked all over, I've studied MSDN, I've searched all the places I can, but I can't figure out what the problem is. It's probably just something I overlooked, but I'm tearing my hair out here and I could use a bit of help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing the file move outside the isoStream using statement?

Comment: Heyy, that did it. Thanks, @archon. I don't know why I didn't think of that. It didn't seem like something that would matter, heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on [archon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2966665/archon) comment, the move operation fails because it's inside the using block.  Changing the code as follows fixes the problem.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = 
            new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Temp.utc", FileMode.Create, stored)) 
{
    BinaryFormatter bform = new BinaryFormatter();
    bform.Serialize(isoStream, gradebook);
}
stored.DeleteFile("Gradebook.utc");
stored.MoveFile("Temp.utc", "Gradebook.utc");
```

The reason *why* it fails is that the using block has the file `Temp.utc` open, and an open file can't be moved. Once execution leaves the using block, the `Dispose` method is called on `isoStream` which causes it to close the open file.

Comment: Thanks man. That seems like it should be an obvious answer, but I guess I never thought of it right.